# Ibatis , oracle and how to map a old procedure that return "columns"

Tags: oracle, dictionary, ibatis

I have the next procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Package PC.PCS_Material_Pkg 
As
TYPE Code_material_of_arr IS TABLE OF Number(30) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE Desc_Material_Of_arr IS TABLE OF Varchar2(240) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
Procedure PCS_Material
   ( SRV_Message                    In Out     Varchar2
    , In_xDesc_Material              In         Varchar2
    , Col_Codi_material_of           Out        Code_material_of_arr
    , Col_Desc_Material_Of           Out        Desc_Material_Of_arr
    );
End PCS_Material_Pkg;
/
```

And i wish to know how to map it (xml) at least some clue of how to proceed. Sadly, i can't change the procedure and return a cursor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate on the question..

Ibatis, usually has a sqlMap.xml file, in which you can write all the queries, and get a resultObject in return.

All you would really need to do is, provide Oracle DB drivers to Ibatis, and a query you want to run , in an xml file.

Comment: i can connect to oracle using ibatis but i don't know how to connect with *THIS* procedure in particular. This procedure *DOES NOT* return a cursor, instead it return a custom type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example (taken from another question). Note the mode of the params. You'll want to use Oracle jdbcTypes, but this should send you in the right direction.

```
<parameterMap id="mapping-description-modifiable" class="java.util.Map">           
    <parameter property="id" javaType="java.lang.Long" jdbcType="NUMERIC" mode="INOUT"/>         
    <parameter property="lang" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="IN"/>         
    <parameter property="shortDesc" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="IN"/>         
    <parameter property="fullDesc" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="IN"/>         
    <parameter property="modify" javaType="boolean" jdbcType="NUMBER" mode="IN"/>     
</parameterMap> 
<procedure id="add-description" arameterMap="mapping-description-modifiable">         
     {call COM_DESCRIPTION_PKG.add_desc(?,?,?,?,?)} 
</procedure>
```

Comment: thanks but it does not work. It work with a primitive as return date but this function return custom type.  I tried jdbctype=array object and type and nothing works.